# Android Volley RequestFuture always timing out

Tags: android, android-volley

I want to load some data on application startup that will be used by all activities.
I do this in the application's onCreate method and because I want this data to be downloaded before any activity is shown, I try to make a synchronous request using RequestFuture. However the TimeoutException is always thrown.

```html
public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();
        
        appRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        RequestFuture<JSONArray> requestFuture = RequestFuture.newFuture();
        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(
                URL,
                requestFuture,
                requestFuture);

        appRequestQueue.add(request);

        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = requestFuture.get(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            
            // Do processing. Never gets here            


            Log.v("*******************", "Application initialized");
            
        } catch (JSONException je) {

        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        } catch (ExecutionException ee) {
        } catch (TimeoutException te) {
            // Always times out
            Log.v("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$", "It has timed out...");

        }
```

What is the best way to get app-wide data keeping in mind that there is no one activity that is started first?

Comment: Were you able to identify the problem?

Comment: Did you try retry policy and increase your default timeout value ?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, according to the default behavior of the volley, the wake up notification (the delivery of the response) of the Request is posted on the Handler of the main UI thread.

So when the UI thread is blocked, the wake up notification will never be executed (also the response will never be delivered), and you'll always get a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this recently, the solution is to NOT make requests or handle them from the main thread ( UI ), it always throws a `TimeoutException` . Consider creating a `AsyncTask` and performing this request from there.

You can communicate with the MainActivity using the `onPostExecute` callback.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html